# How to cross the Right edge of a control with the Right edge of the Windows Form window?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working C# Winform.

And have a `Label` control which name is: `lblName`

I want to set the position of this control as: It's the Right side been cross to the Right side of the it's parent `Windows Form`.

I used the code below:

```
this.lblName.Left = this.Width - this.lblName.Width;
```

In the Windows Form code.

But the `lblName` control been exits the border of the page and seems the `this.Width` is larger than the Windows form window Width!

Where is my mistake and what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Width` property includes the width of the borders.

Instead, you should use the `ClientRectangle` property, which does not include borders.

```
lblName.Left = this.ClientRectangle.Width - lblName.Width;
```